# Unreal Engine 5.0.3 ERROR: Could not find NetFxSDK install dir

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

I was trying to create a new *C++* Unreal Engine project, but every time I do it (Only with C++), I get a popping window that says:

```
Running C:/Program Files/Epic Games/UE_5.0/Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool/UnrealBuildTool.exe  -projectfiles -project="C:/Users/user/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject/MyProject.uproject" -game -rocket -progress
Log file: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\UnrealBuildTool\Log_GPF.txt

Some Platforms were skipped due to invalid SDK setup: IOS, Android, Linux, LinuxArm64.
See the log file for detailed information

Discovering modules, targets and source code for project...
ERROR: Could not find NetFxSDK install dir; this will prevent SwarmInterface from installing.  Install a version of .NET Framework SDK at 4.6.0 or higher.
```

Comment: Even though you're coding in C++ ... the UnrealBuildTool.exe is apparently dependent on .NET.  Just follow the instructions in the error message: `Install a version of .NET Framework SDK at 4.6.0 or higher.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had this same problem earlier today.
From Visual Studio Installer you can install .NET Framework SDK 4.6.0

[Main GUI for Visual Studio Install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMxEA.png)
From here click on the modify button to add features and functionally.

[Modifying VS Installer Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hz6hY.png)
Then you just need to check the box for the .NET Framework and follow the install steps.

This worked for me, hopefully it'll work for you too!

Comment: Thanks dude, it worked! I just don't understand why it wasn't working before, I had already downloaded a higher version of the framework: SDK 6.0